# Can I list Tabs of a "MozillaWindowClass" HWND via XPCOM?

Tags: c++, firefox, xpcom, geckosdk

*`IE` provides easy access to a `IWebBrowser2` and `IHtmlDocument2` from a `HWND` of a IE Frame.* So you `EnumWindows` and `EnumChildWindows` and then you test the class and once you find the right ones, you can easily interact with them.

> **If there a way to list all open Mozilla Firefox tabs in a `"MozillaWindowClass"` *(having its `HWND`)*, via `XPCOM` and C++?**

*I've googled long and strong but can't find much on the subject. I don't want to develop an extension / add-on but want to control the browser externally from an unrelated EXE, not from an extension DLL. Or at least some read-only access to it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **You can not use C++/XPCOM with Firefox externally like you use COM with IE, you can only use C++/XPCOM from within a binary component of your extension.** *So you won't be able to do it without writing an extension, and at that point it's easier to listen on tab events from JS and notify your binary component.*

Note that supporting binary components in a FF is a PITA so I don't suggest you take that road without a good reason.

However, once you have an extension and a binary component the way to get a HWND from a tab is this (hope it still works, we stopped supporting FF many versions back):

```
static HWND GetWndHandle(nsIXULWindow * window) {
    HWND hwnd = NULL;

    nsCOMPtr<nsIDocShell> docshell;
    nsresult res = window->GetDocShell(getter_AddRefs(docshell));

    if(NS_SUCCEEDED(res)) {
        nsCOMPtr<nsIBaseWindow> basewnd(do_QueryInterface(docshell));

        if(basewnd) {
            res = basewnd->GetParentNativeWindow((nativeWindow*)&hwnd);
            if(NS_FAILED(res)) hwnd = NULL;
        }
    }

    return hwnd;
}
```

With this and the notifications from the JS your binary component could provide a look up to find a tab by HWND and do stuff with it.